# Is my logic for this EER diagram correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, cardinality

I'm practicing creating EER schemas for an exam and was wondering if my logic for this EER diagram for the circled part is correct. Something tells me I'm wrong:

[image]

I'm trying to say that for the dealership branch, it has many vehicles, hence, **1:N**.

Though, I feel like it would make more sense to have a relationship like:
**(0,1):(0,N)** would make more sense because it's possible for the dealership in question may not have the vehicle, hence **0**, and if it does, hence **1**. The dealership branch may have **0** vehicles, or many **(N)** vehicles.

So, this is where I'm stumped at. If someone can explain the logic to me and help me understand my mistake or if I'm correct, that would be great.

Comment: Your diagram and reasoning seem correct to me.  But have you tried to implement this in MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I have not.

Comment: You are mixing two notations (Chen and min-max) here that may mean different things. This is quite uncommon as they describe different things. The 1:n (Chen) says: a dealership branch can have between zero and N vehicles. A vehicle is owned by 0 or 1 dealership branches. Is that what you want to express? A 1:N in Chen would be mapped to (0,N), (0,1) in min-max

Comment: @FrankLauterwald Yes, exactly. So my diagram is correct based on this logic, right?

Comment: Yes it is, but you should stick to one notation (see my edited comment above). (0,N):(0,1) would mean the same thing, while (0,1):(0,N) would not. min-max notation describes how often the entity on the side with the number participates in a relationship => (0,1) on the dealer side means that one dealership can be linked to 0 or 1 vehicles which is not what you want. (0,n) on the other hand means that on dealership can be linked to an arbitrary number of vehicles.